# SQL Wildcard Question

Tags: sql, wildcard

Sorry I am new to working with databases - I am trying to perform a query 
that will get all of the characters that are similar to a string in SQL.

For example,

If I am looking for all users that begin with a certain string, something like S* or Sm* that would return "Smith, Smelly, Smiles, etc..."

Am I on the right track with this?

Any help would be appreciated, and Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that different versions of SQL give you different choices; but they all support `%`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`LIKE`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) operator is what you are searching for, so for your example you would need something like:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM [Users]
 WHERE LastName LIKE 'S%'
```

The `%` character is the wild-card in SQL.

Comment: This is what I was searching for - as I just really needed something to find names and other fields that "started with" a specific string. Sorry for my poor wording.

Answer (score 10):

Sql can't do this ... placing the percentage symbol in the middle.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE last_name LIKE 'S%th'
```

you would need to write a where clause and an and clause.

```
 SELECT * FROM users WHERE last_name LIKE 'S%' and last_name LIKE '%th'
```

Comment: MSSQL (tested with version 2019) can find wildcards in the middle of a string. So 'S%th' will match 'Smith'.

Answer (score 5):

Standard (ANSI) SQL has two wildcard characters for use with the LIKE keyword:

- **_** (underscore). Matches a single occurrence of any single character.
- **%** (percent sign). Matches zero or more occurrences of any single character.

In addition, SQL Server extends the LIKE wildcard matching to include character set specification, rather like a normal regular expresion character set specifier:

- **[character-set]** Matches a single character from the specified set
- **[^character-set]** Matches a single character not in the specified set.

Character sets may be specified in the normal way as a range as well:

- [0-9] matches any decimal digit.
- [A-Z] matches any upper-case letter
- [^A-Z0-9-] matches any character that isn't a letter, digit or hyphen.

The semantics of letter matching of course, a dependent on the collation sequence in use. It may or may not be case-sensitive.

Further, to match a literal left square bracket ('[]'), you **must** use the character range specifier. You won't get a syntax error, but you won't get a match, either.

```
where x.field like 'x[[][0-9]]'
```

will match text that looks like 'x[0]' , 'x[8]', etc. But

```
where 'abc[x' like 'abc[x'
```

will always be false.

Answer (score 4):

to get all the users with a lastname of smith

```
SELECT * 
  FROM [Users]
 WHERE LastName ='Smith'
```

to get all users where the lastname contains  smith do this, that will also return blasmith, smith2 etc etc

```
SELECT * 
  FROM [Users]
 WHERE LastName LIKE '%Smith%'
```

If you want everything that starts with smith do this

```
SELECT * 
  FROM [Users]
 WHERE LastName LIKE 'Smith%'
```

Comment: the above will work only in a case-insensitive collation. cf. Blasmith would not match `%Smith%` in case-sensitive collations.  This issue can be avoided by changing the where clause to e.g. `WHERE LOWER(LastName) LIKE '%smith%'` regardless of collation. Some collations may further mark differences like `smîth` (note the `î`) as matches, while others may mark them as non-matches.

Answer (score 1):

you might also like the results of `SOUNDEX`, depending on your preference for last name similarity.

```
select * 
from [users]
where soundex('lastname') = soundex( 'Smith' )
or upper(lastname) like 'SM%'
```

Comment: Except that soundex isn't very good (e.g., something like a 60% false positive rate has been observed). It was designed for matching english-language names, not arbitrary words. It's falls on its face given arbitrary text (or text outside the 26 base letters of the alphabet). Here's the original patent from 1917.

http://www.google.com/patents/about?id=EbdgAAAAEBAJ&dq=1,261,167

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't entirely clear.

If you want all the users with last name Smith, a regular search will work:

```
 SELECT * FROM users WHERE last_name = 'Smith'
```

If you want all the users beginning with 'S' and ending in 'th', you can use LIKE and a wildcard:

```
 SELECT * FROM users WHERE last_name LIKE 'S%th'
```

(Note the standard SQL many wildcard of '%' rather than '*').

If you really want a "sounds like" match, many databases support one or more SOUNDEX algorithm searches.  Check the documentation for your specific product (which you don't mention in the question).